# Subprocess does not work with pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, pyinstaller

I have the following sample script that works fine from Spyder. As an example I used Windows command `dir /w`. My real issue is an external utility that I need to launch, but this simple example shows the same issue:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

scriptpath=os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

def doit():
    cmdlst = ["dir", "/w"]
    foutput=scriptpath + "\\" + "result.txt"
    
    if os.path.exists(foutput):
      os.remove(foutput)
    with open(foutput, "w") as fresult:  
      result = subprocess.run(cmdlst, stdout=fresult, text=True, shell=True)


myDia = tk.Tk()
bt1=tk.Button(myDia, text="DoIt", command=doit, width=16, height=2)
bt1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='W', padx=0, pady=0)

myDia.mainloop()
```

When I compile it from the Anaconda prompt with:

`pyinstaller --onefile subproc.pyw`

it will generate the exe. When running it, it will launch the dialog. When pressing the button it will create an empty file "result.txt", but there is no content and no error! The program just hangs.

Why doesn't the compiled exe give the expected result like the `.pyw` file in Spyder?
Please note that the Tkinter dialog seems to be relevant in causing this issue. Removing the Tkinter dialog and renaming the file to .py results in a working compiled program.

Comment: Can anyone reproduce this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.13 and PyInstaller 5.3.  The `result.txt` is created inside the temporary directory with the directory content.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for checking. It triggered me to test with Python 3.9 and Pyinstaller 5.1 and I can confirm that this works as you described. So it must be some issue solved in a newer version (issue was detected with Python 3.7 and pyinstaller 4.1